# XOR Linked List with c++

Tags: c++

So I have tried to implement XOR linked list in c++ myself and I came up with something like this

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Node {
    int data;
    Node* npx;
};

Node* XOR(Node* prev, Node* next) {
    return (Node *)((uintptr_t)(prev) ^ (uintptr_t)(next));
}

// add a new node to linked list head is the beginign of the list
void Add(Node **head, int data) {
    Node* newNode = new Node();
    newNode->data = data;
    if (head = NULL) {
        cout << "no head";
    }
    else {
        while (XOR(*head, (*head)->npx) != NULL) {
            *head = XOR(*head, (*head)->npx);
        }
        (*head)->npx = XOR(XOR((*head)->npx, XOR(*head, (*head)->npx)), newNode);

    }

}
//geting data from the list with given indx
int Get(int index, Node* head) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= index; i++) {
        if (XOR(head, head->npx) != NULL) {
            head = XOR(head, head->npx);
        }
        else {
            cout << "index out of range";
        }
    }
    return head->data;
}


int main()
{
    Node** newNode = new Node* ();

    Add(newNode, 10);
    Add(newNode, 2);
    cout << Get(1, *newNode);
    return 0;
}
```

however it does not return anything even with the hardcoded test, could anyone help me or show what the solution should look like?

Comment: Related: Turn up the compiler warning and turn them up **LOUD**. They are the first defense against trivial mistakes like `if (head = NULL) {`

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a free debugging service, and you should show your attempts at debugging the code with a debugger or other simpler methods such as debug print statements. You can also test each part of the code separately to figure out exactly which part of the code is causing the problem. This won't be the only time you end up with a bug in your code, and learning to debug your programs will help you much more than having someone find the bug for you. http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/

Comment: And when debugging, pay special attention to when you use `npx` relative to when you set `npx` Just like you should with a regular linked list, draw everything out with pencil and paper, all of the functions and all of the steps, so that you have some expectations to compare against what you get when stepping the debugger .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problem 1: = used in place of ==

```
if (head = NULL)
```

immediately destroyed the `head` pointer. This mistake will be marked by many modern compilers. It is not a compiler error, setting `head` to `NULL`  is perfectly legal even in an `if` statement, but since it is almost always a logical mistake, a good compiler will bring it to your attention. Sometimes you have to ask the compiler to do it, though. Turn up the warning level as high as you can tolerate and you'll usually save time on debugging typos and the little oopsies.

## Problem 2: Add always advances the head to the end of the list

Since head is passed by pointer, advancing the head updates the caller's head pointer and loses the list. `Add` does need to update the `head` pointer, but only if the list is empty.

## Problem 3: the previous node is not properly tracked

This makes making `npx = previous ^ next` difficult to compute. You always need to know two nodes to recover the third, and the previous node can be recovered, but it's much easier to simply hold onto it.

## Solution:

I'm trying to under-complicate this so forgive me if the code is stupid and poorly optimized. Comments on what I'm doing and why are embedded in the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std; // reconsider using this. It can have negative side 
                     // effects when your programs get more complicated 

struct Node; // Forward declaration 
             // XOR needs Node, and a small change to Node meant Node needed XOR
             // this struck me as the most-polite way to resolve the circle

// Unchanged
Node* XOR(Node* prev, Node* next) {
    return (Node *)((uintptr_t)(prev) ^ (uintptr_t)(next));
}

struct Node {
    int data;
    Node* npx;
    // add a constructor to make life easier. npx is always computed correctly
    Node(int data, Node* prev, Node * next): data(data), npx(XOR(prev, next))
    {

    }
    // TODO: GetNext and GetPrev functions could be useful here. eg:
    Node * GetNext(Node * prev)
    {
        return XOR(prev, npx);
    }
    // Along  with a link(prev, next) function this would let you hide the XOR and 
    // abstract away all external knowledge of how the linked list is connected from 
    // the user.
};

// add a new node to linked list head is the beginning of the list
void Add(Node * &head, int data) { // note: using reference rather than double pointer
    if (head == nullptr) { // no head, not much to do
        head = new Node(data, nullptr, nullptr); // there is no prev or next
                                                 // if there is only one node
    }
    else {
        // book keeping
        Node * prev = nullptr; // last node visited. On first node, so null
                               // NOTE: THIS IS A (sort of) LIE! This implementation 
                               // CANNOT be called with a Node from the the middle of a 
                               // a list. Sometimes you want this functionality (Why 
                               // search the whole damn list if you're already part 
                               // way through?) but to get it, you have to provide more 
                               // information so that you can recover the next pointer.
        Node * cur = head; // current node is head
        Node * next = XOR(prev, cur->npx); // next node is prev XOR npx
        // OR Node * next = cur->GetNext(prev);

        while (next != nullptr) { // there is a node here. Advance to next
            prev = cur;
            cur = next;
            next = XOR(prev, cur->npx);
        }
        // found last node. Append new node
        Node * newNode = new Node(data, cur, nullptr); // new tail node, so
                                                       // npx = current node XOR null
        cur->npx = XOR(prev, newNode); // current node now has a next. Update npx
                                       // here is where a cur->link(prev, newNode) function
                                       // would be handy.
    }
}

//getting data from the list with given index
int Get(int index, Node* cur) {
    Node * prev = nullptr; // is no previous node yet
    while (index && // exit when we've iterated far enough
            cur != nullptr) { // or we've run out of nodes
        Node * next =  XOR(prev, cur->npx); // find next node
        prev = cur; // update book keeping
        cur = next;
        index--; // one less iteration
    }
    if (index != 0) // oops.
    {
        // throwing exception rather than allowing the function to return an
        // incorrect value. Often the correct choice unless incorrect indexes
        // is a common occurrence. If something happens often it is not
        //exceptional and thus should not be an exception.
        throw std::out_of_range("index out of range");
    }
    return cur->data;
}


int main()
{
    Node* head = nullptr; //no need for dynamic allocation

    Add(head, 10); //
    Add(head, 2);
    Add(head, 42); // added one more just to be sure
    cout << Get(0, head) << '\n'; // testing that the program can read all elements
    cout << Get(1, head) << '\n';
    cout << Get(2, head) << '\n';

    // TODO: iterate through list and free all of the allocated memory
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the insight you gave it really helped however could you explain a little bit more what do you mean by the link function should it be something like Node* Link(Node* prev, Node* next) {
  return XOR(prev, next);
 } or something more advanced (if so what should it do and return)?

Comment: @puma Close. `link` would be a setter function for `npx`. It returns nothing. Something like `void link(Node* prev, node * next) { npx = XOR(prev, next); } `  f you have `GetNext`, `GetPrev` and `Link` methods for `Node`, the benefits are readability (GetNext's purpose is obvious), reduced code duplication (won't have six identical calls to XOR and a typo in the seventh), and increased encapsulation.  `npx` can be private and you can switch back and forth between traditional, two-pointer-based doubly linked lists and XOR linked list without having to change anything but the `Node` structure.

Comment: Just to complement, I follow this style: when you have to compare a variable to a constant, always put the constant on the left side `if (NULL == head)`, because in a situation that you use a assignment operator `=` instead of equality operator `==` the compiler will show and error because assignment to a constant, easier to find the error.